# iPhone has suddenly "forgotten" Wifi SSID passwords

Tags: iphone, wifi, password

My iPhone is now prompting for the home wifi password.  I was under the impression that it was designed to be "set it and forget it".   Did it "forget" the password?  Or is this somehow normal?  Is there is anything I can do (e.g. setting), to help it to remember?

The wifi password has NOT changed.

Comment: It is not normal, and you should indeed be able to set the password and not need to re-enter it again. Something may have happened to the network settings and iOS reset them. Just guessing here but if it keeps happening I would back up the phone and do an erase and re-install to bringiOS back to as-new condition.

Comment: Do you use iCloud Keychain ?

Comment: Yes to iCloud Keychain